# Maximum Date Per Group in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have found similar questions to this but nothing working with dates in DataFrames grouped by multiple columns.

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    person_ref  post_start   post_number  post_title                   change_date
0   123         2010-08-08   000492       Doorman                      2014-04-17
1   123         2010-08-08   000492       Doorman/Porter               2014-01-14
2   123         2010-08-08   000492       Uniformed Security Officer   2005-12-16
3   123         2011-04-03   000554       Security Officer             2011-01-01
4   123         2010-07-15   000568       Night Security Officer       2010-06-30
5   456         2012-09-17   5080         HR Systems & MI Analyst      2013-08-13
6   456         2012-09-17   5080         HR Systems & MI Adviser      2011-04-07
7   456         2012-09-17   5080         HRIS Adviser                 2010-06-14
8   456         2012-09-17   5080         HR Systems Assistant         2007-09-21
```

This shows two employees (`person_ref`), the posts that they have held (`post_number`), and the titles that the posts have had through their history (`post_title`). `post_start` is the date that the employee started in the post, and `change_date` is the date that the post title was changed.

I want to end up with a DataFrame that shows for each employee only the post title when they started in post:

```
    person_ref  post_start   post_number  post_title                   change_date
0   123         2010-08-08   000492       Uniformed Security Officer   2005-12-16
1   123         2011-04-03   000554       Security Officer             2011-01-01
2   123         2010-07-15   000568       Night Security Officer       2010-06-30
3   456         2012-09-17   5080         HR Systems & MI Adviser      2011-04-07
```

What this boils down to is the maximum `change_date` that is less than or equal to the `post_start` date per `person_ref` per `post_number`.

How I can achieve this in pandas? I guess I need to group by `person_ref` and `post_number`, but I'm struggling to then get only the row with the correct change date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df[(df.change_date <= df.post_start)]
    .sort_values(
         by=['person_ref','post_number','post_start','change_date'],
         ascending=[1,1,1,0])
    .groupby(['person_ref','post_number'])
    .first().reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. This almost worked but brought back the HR Systems Assistant rather than HR Systems & MI Adviser for person 456

Comment: try that :df[(df.change_date <= df.post_start)].sort(['person_ref','post_number','post_start','change_date'],ascending=[1,1,1,0]).groupby(['person_ref','post_number']).first().reset_index()

Comment: You should put that into a code block so it's more easily understood. A better answer would also explain what exactly is happening for the benefit of future readers.